# Automation error using SQL queries in a loop

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to run a loop through a table that takes relevant information and then inserts it into a VFP9 .dbf table. However, I keep getting an automation error ('-2147217913 (80040e07)'). It seems to run the first time just fine, inserting into a table a single time before erroring out. I've made it print out the string every time with the execution part of the code commented out, but the SQL looks perfectly fine. What is the issue here?

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

sConnString = "DSN=Visual FoxPro Tables;UID=;SourceDB=s:\accounting\db;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString

For i = 1 To [RawTable].Rows.Count
        vStatement = "dong!"
        vAccount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns("account").Index)
        vCardUser = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns("card member").Index)
        vDate = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns("date").Index)
        vDesc = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns("description").Index)
        vAmount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns("amount").Index)

        MsgBox "INSERT INTO amex_dist (Statement,Account,Card_user,Date,Desc,Amount) VALUES ('" & vStatement & "','" & vAccount & "','" & vCardUser & "','" & vDate & "','" & vDesc & "'," & vAmount & ")"

        conn.Execute ("INSERT INTO amex_dist (Statement,Account,Card_user,Date,Desc,Amount) VALUES ('" & vStatement & "','" & vAccount & "','" & vCardUser & "','" & vDate & "','" & vDesc & "'," & vAmount & ")")
Next i
MsgBox "done :)", vbInformation
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

EDIT: Here is an example of what the table will look like.

```
date       receipt  description card member account #          amount   account
07/01/2016          Purchase     Employee   XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX   9.95    41000-000-00
07/01/2016          Purchase     Employee   XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX   33      41000-000-00
06/29/2016          Purchase     Employee   XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX   64      41000-000-00
```

Comment: Use an `ADO.Command` to pass your INSERT instead of using `.Execute` directly on the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Foxpro doesn't like receiving dates as just `String` literals or series of numbers. Try using the `CTOD` function (Characters to Date) and see if that resolves the problem. The `Execute` line should look like:

```
conn.Execute ("INSERT INTO amex_dist (Statement,Account,Card_user,Date,Desc,Amount) VALUES ('" & vStatement & "','" & vAccount & "','" & vCardUser & "',CTOD('" & vDate & "'),'" & vDesc & "'," & vAmount & ")")
```